# Update with Subquery non relational table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have the follow sql query but when I execute It gives me a message error: `Unknown column 't1.ip' in 'where clause'`.
If I hard code `t1.ip` in subquery just for testing, It works perfectly.

```
UPDATE
    report_a t1,
    (SELECT
        location.country, region.name, location.city
    FROM
        geoip
    INNER JOIN
        location
    ON
        geoip.locId = location.locId
    INNER JOIN
        region
    ON
        region.country = location.country
    AND
        region.region = location.region
    WHERE
        INET_ATON(t1.ip) BETWEEN startIpNum AND endIpNum
    LIMIT 1) AS t2
    SET
        t1.country = t2.country,
        t1.city = t2.city,
        t1.state = t2.name;
```

Someone have any idea how i can do this query?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a `join`.  I am a bit unclear on what the `LIMIT 1` is supposed to be doing.  I moved that into the outer query, although that might not be correct:

```
UPDATE report_a t1,
       (SELECT location.country, region.name, location.city, startIpNum, endIpNum
        FROM geoip INNER JOIN
             location
             ON geoip.locId = location.locId INNER JOIN 
             region
             ON region.country = location.country AND
                region.region = location.region
       ) glr
       ON INET_ATON(t1.ip) BETWEEN glr.startIpNum AND glr.endIpNum
    SET t1.country = t2.country,
        t1.city = t2.city,
        t1.state = t2.name
    LIMIT 1;
```

As I think about it, you probably do not want the `LIMIT 1`.  Why would there be multiple matches to the subquery?

Comment: It almost work! I've changed the `ON` to `WHERE`. Using `LIMIT 1` was a manufacturer's recommendation but I think it shouldn't have multiple matches.